# check password from database php

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, session

I am trying take some data of a specific row from the table users by checking if the username and password are correct. 
I cant see why it is not working!!

**EDIT:** I insert the code of the whole page. I am using to form because i in the same form i have the register button and the log in button. I am checking which one the user pressed and then do things.

```
$host = "xx";
$user = "xx";
$pass= "xx";
$dbname = "xx";
$conn = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass, $dbname );

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed : ".$conn->connect_error); //fixme
}

if ( isset($_POST['login'])  ) {

    if ($_POST["actionb"] == 'Login') {

        $username = isset($_POST["username"]) ? $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["username"]) : "";
        $password = isset($_POST["password"]) ? $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["password"]) : "";

        echo $username;
        echo $password;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
        $results=$conn->query($query);


        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0 ) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $email = $row["email"];
                    $postalcode = $row["postalcode"];
                    $phonenumber = $row["phonenumber"];
                }
            }
            $_SESSION['postalcode'] = $postalcode;
            $_SESSION['phonenumber'] = $phonenumber;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            echo "You are now logged in";
            header('location: confirm.php');
        } else {
            //echo "Wrong username/password combination";
        }
    }
}
?>

<html>
    <style type ="text/css">
        ...
    </style>

<body>

<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>For existing users</h1>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="actionb" value="Login" >

    <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter username" name="username" required>

    <label for="password"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="password2" required>

    <div class="clearfix">
        <button type="submit" name="login" value="Login">Login</button>
    </div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is not working? what is the output?

Comment: please stop storing plain text passwords its terrible practice, and compromises  both you and your users.

Comment: keeps telling"Wrong username/password combination"; @user969068

Comment: because you maybe forgot to connect mysql before executing your query? Do you have mysqli_connect with right credentials in your code?

Comment: @user969068 yes i use " $conn = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass, $dbname ); " and it connects fine

Comment: oh ok, I noticed that error you are hardcoding in your code...are you storing plain passwords or encrypted?

Comment: @user969068 well sorry for asking that, but how i check what i am storing? :D I mean in my database i define the password field with "varchar(255) latin1_swedish_ci" ,in html the field is type=password

Comment: you're outputting before header here. Turn on error reporting.

Comment: fixed that. still doesnt working.

Comment: Fixed what? I still see an echo and a header. Right here `echo "You are now logged in";
            header('location: confirm.php')` and I am pretty sure that that is all that's wrong here.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Altough you're right about the `echo` and `header` not being correct, the OP stated the script doesn't even get to that code (goes to the `else`), so first problem first :)

Comment: @Philip Ok so I was wrong about my saying if that was all was wrong, I stand corrected. However, if they say it's not getting there, then something else failed and asked them to turn on error reporting in [an earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53037502/check-password-from-database-php?noredirect=1#comment92975917_53037502) which they didn't respond back for.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Very true, I included your remarks in my answer

Answer (score 1):

First: like @IdontDownVote said, you should always(!) hash/encrypt passwords before storing them in a database (see php.net/manual/en/book.password.php). One hack and all your users will hate you for not doing it. ;)

Second: can it be you are getting more then one row back? (As presumed by your `if ($results->num_rows > 0) {` later in the code.) The error also fires then, because you check for `==1`, might change it to `>0`.

Third: check if the `mysqli_query()` call was successfull by added it in your `if` statement with `$results && mysqli_num_rows(..etc..`

Fourth: the password is actually send as `$_POST['password2']`

Fifth: (As @FunkFortyNiner pointed out correctly) using `header()` as a redirection must be the first thing to output to the browser (so no `echo`'s before that) and followed by a `exit();` to prevent something else `echo`-ing after that (which is also not valid in PHP).

Sixth: (As @FunkFortyNiner pointed out as well) While developing, always turn error reporting on using `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT | E_NOTICE);` and
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of you PHP. This way all errors, warnings etc are explicitly printed in the browser, so you can debug/clean/fix.

Comment: nothing worked, i tried to do echo $password just to see if im getting the password and it doesnot echoing anything @Philip

Comment: Then the $_POST['password'] is not set or empty. Is this after a form post? And can you provide the form code in your question?

Comment: i added the whole page code

Comment: Yeah, in the login form the name of the password field is `password2` not `password`, so it would be `$_POST['password2']` (or change the input's `name`)

Comment: You're welcome. Still have a look at the other problems before putting it online ;)